# Integral of $\sqrt {-\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t - \tan^2 t}$

Tags: integration, arc-length

$$\int{\sqrt {(-\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t - \tan^2 t)}}~\textrm{d}t$$

I'm aware of a few trig identities, such as ${\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t} = \cos (2t)$ and $\tan^2 t = \frac{\sin^2 t}{\cos^2 t}$ but these don't seem to help simplify the problem.

No simple $u$-substitution seems to prevent itself, and my attempt to integrate by parts has resulted in an even more difficult integrand.

WolframAlpha and a few different integral calculators cannot seem to solve this.

Comment: The identity $1+\tan^2 t=\sec^2t$ might be useful, you could certainly try a substitution with $u=\cos t$ at that point...

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Hint:Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSubstitution.html

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Find the length of the curve:  $r(t) = \cos t \;\mathbf i + \sin t \;\mathbf j + \ln{ \cos t} \;\mathbf k, 0 \le t \le \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: @alphanumeric0: where the minus sign before $\sin^2 t$ comes from, in such a case? You actually have to integrate $\sqrt{1+\tan^2 t}\,dt$, that is **way** easier than what you asked.

Comment: The wanted length is just $\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)=\log(1+\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yep, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

By enforcing the substitution $t=\arcsin u$ we are left with
$$ \int\sqrt{1-4u^2+2u^4}\frac{du}{1-u^2}=\int\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{(1-u^2)^2}}\,du $$
or, by setting $\frac{1}{1-u^2}=v$, 
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{2-v^2}}{2v^{3/2}\sqrt{v-1}}\,dv$$
which boils down to an elliptic integral. So, no simple answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int{\sqrt{-\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)-\tan^2(t)}}\,dt$$
We have$$\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)=\cos(2t)$$$$\tan^2(t)=\sec^2(t)-1$$
$$\sec(t)=\frac{1}{\cos(t)}$$$$\cos^2(t)=\frac{1+\cos(2t)}{2}$$
The integral becomes:$$\int{\sqrt{\cos(2t)-\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}+1}}dt$$
$$\int{\sqrt{\cos(2t)-\frac{2}{1+\cos(2t)}+1}}dt$$
$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{\cos(2t)+\cos^2(2t)-2+1+\cos(2t)}{1+\cos(2t)}}}dt$$$$\int{\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(2t)+2\cos(2t)-1}{1+\cos(2t)}}}dt$$
Let $u=\cos(2t)$ then $du=-2\sin(2t)dt$ and $sin(2t)=\sqrt{1-u^2}$

$$\frac{1}{-2}\int{\sqrt{\frac{u^2+2u-1}{(1-u^2)(1+u)}}}du$$
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\int{\sqrt{\frac{(1+u)^2-2}{(1-u)(1+u)^2}}}du$$

Comment: $\sin(2t)=\sqrt{1-u^2}$

Comment: It gets messy, so I plotted the function $F(t)=\sqrt{-sin^2(t)+cos^2(t)-tan^2(t)}$. It's an even function. The next step is to get its polynomial approximation and then integrate it.

Comment: The next step is to get its polynomial approximation and then integrate it. Since it is an even function the polynomial will include only even powers, $F(t)=c_0+c_1x^2+c_2x^4+...+c_{2n}x^{2n}$.

Comment: Maybe it ends like that...

Comment: What if we use the equation of a semi ellipse know as $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, so our equation will be $y=\sqrt{1-\frac{t^2}{0.572^2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

After trying other methods, I plot the function and I get an elliptic function so I use the semi-ellipse equation to solve the integral.
the equation of a semi ellipse known as $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, so our equation will be $$\frac{t^2}{0.572^2}+{y^2}={1}$$
then the equation can be written as :
$$y=\sqrt{1-(\frac{t}{0.572})^2}$$
So $$f(t)=\sqrt{1-(\frac{t}{0.572})^2}$$
the intgral will be
$$I=\int\sqrt{1-(\frac{t}{0.572})^2}\,dt$$
The final result is
$$I=\frac{1}{1.144}(t\sqrt{{0.572}^2-({t})^2}+{0.572}^2\arcsin{\frac{t}{0.572}})+C$$

Comment: What are you doing?